# is there any way to disable send button until message got typed in the message field without onchange method in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, My objective is to disable send button until message got typed in the message field or to show some `popup` without writing anything in textfield and clicking on `send button`. For **Disabling** - I've tried by giving `onChange method` but due to `onchange` method input field is getting laggy. That's why i'm using Id. Can anyone suggest me any way of disabling the button ?

Here is the code:

```
class Data extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { isSender: true, content: "hello" },
        { isSender: false, content: "hello1" },
        { isSender: true, content: "hello2" },
        { isSender: false, content: "hello3" },
        { isSender: true, content: "hello4" },
        { isSender: false, content: "hello5" },
        { isSender: true, content: "hello6" },
        { isSender: false, content: "hello7" }
      ],
      msg: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  scrollToBottom = () => {
    this.messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    console.log(text);
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardHeader
          avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">S</Avatar>}
          title={
            <>
              <InputBase placeholder="Search Google Maps" margin="normal" />
              <IconButton type="submit" aria-label="search">
                <SearchIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </>
          }
        />
        <Divider />
        <CardContent
          style={{ overflow: "scroll" }}
          className={classes.contentHeight}
          id="chatList"
        >
          <div>
            <Message isSender content="Hello" />
            {this.state.data.map(item => {
              if (item.isSender) {
                return <Message isSender content={item.content} />;
              }
              return <Message content={item.content} />;
            })}
          </div>
          <div
            style={{ float: "left", clear: "both" }}
            ref={el => {
              this.messagesEnd = el;
            }}
          />
        </CardContent>
        <Divider />
        <CardActions>
          <Paper className={classes.contentPaper}>
            <Input
              margin="dense"
              className={classes.input}
              placeholder="Enter a Message"
              disableUnderline
              name="msg"
              id="text"
            />
            <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send</Button>
          </Paper>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

Either the send button needs to disable or while clicking on the send button without typing anything in input field - it should show snackbar at the top of the textfield as "Enter something".

Can anyone please help me in this?

[Here is the whole code:](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cerf-k1zyb)

Answer (score 1):

You should update state on onChange for input

```
<Input
 margin="dense"
 className={classes.input}
 placeholder="Enter a Message"
 disableUnderline
 name="msg"
 id="text"
 onChange={e => this.setState({ msg: e.target.value })}
/>
```

And disable attribute to Button

```
<Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} disabled={!this.state.msg.length}>
  Send
</Button>
```

Try to avoid `document.getElementById("text").value` in react, it's better to use `state` or `ref`

Comment: I've tried by giving onChange but the issue is input field is getting slow while typing. that's why opted for id. Earlier i used to give onChange method for disabling as you have given above. Could you suggest me any other type?

Comment: do you experience it on codesandbox or locally?
it works fine for me, i am able to click on any keyboard key and it appears immediately

Comment: also do you really need this
```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }
```

Comment: I'm experiencing locally.... Actually we need componentDidupdate for scrolling bottom as well as scrolling up

Comment: It is not working locally, but it is working in sandbox. Don't know why facing this issue

Comment: I downloaded and run your code from codesandbox locally
everything works fine

Does code on codesandbox the same as you have locally?

Comment: Nope, a bit different... I mean like locally it have many components.. the whole conversation have one component and enter message is another component. I have just provided a sample code.

Comment: problem can be, that your component is updated by parent component or redux
you should check if you function componentDidUpdate is not run to often
and debug how often your component is updated

Comment: - Does Input field  is getting slow due to componentDidUpdate?

Comment: We're facing the issue at the time of using Input field. So, thought of using `id` inorder to work appropriately but couldn't able to disable the send button. Is there any way if anyone click on send button then we should get the popup like **Please enter something** ?

Comment: usually componentDidUpdate is not making component slower 
but here we have two point
here you have run function `this.scrollToBottom();`
Second you can put console.log, and check if your component is updated often, so you component is alway update a lot of times.

Comment: is this component what you added to sandbox is the same as you have in code?

Comment: or can you try to move your code to codesandbox so i will be able to see and debug this problem there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213253/discussion-between-sandhya-and-oleksandr-paiziak).